# why my record.setValue({}) is not setting value in afterSubmit event?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

i am setting a field value in a free form text field in my afterSubmit event. Logs are showing the value but the field is not set.
I tried by check and uncheck store-value checkbox, but no change.

My code:

```
    recNew.setValue({
      fieldId: 'custrecord_plc_sup_grade',
      value: 'test'
    })
```

Can anyone suggest me any better solution? i tried the same code on beforeLoad event and it was working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving the record after setting the field?  Since this is an after submit script, you need to save the record for any changes to take effect.